# Getting associated type synonyms with template Haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, type-families, reify, associated-types

Can Template Haskell find out the names and/or the declarations of the associated type synonyms declared in a type class?  I expected [`reify`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/latest/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:reify) would do what I want, but it doesn't seem to provide all the necessary information.  It works for getting function type signatures:

```
% ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
...
Prelude> -- I'll be inserting line breaks and whitespace for clarity
Prelude> -- in all GHCi output.
Prelude> :set -XTemplateHaskell 
Prelude> import Language.Haskell.TH
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> class C a where f :: a -> Int
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> putStrLn $(stringE . show =<< reify ''C)
ClassI (ClassD [] Ghci1.C [PlainTV a_1627398388] []
               [SigD Ghci1.f
                     (ForallT [PlainTV a_1627398388]
                              [ClassP Ghci1.C [VarT a_1627398388]]
                              (AppT (AppT ArrowT (VarT a_1627398388))
                                    (ConT GHC.Types.Int)))])
       []
```

However, adding an associated type synonym to the class causes no change (up to renaming) in the output:

```
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> :set -XTypeFamilies 
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> class C' a where type F a :: * ; f' :: a -> Int
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> putStrLn $(stringE . show =<< reify ''C')
ClassI (ClassD [] Ghci3.C' [PlainTV a_1627405973] []
               [SigD Ghci3.f'
                     (ForallT [PlainTV a_1627405973]
                              [ClassP Ghci3.C' [VarT a_1627405973]]
                              (AppT (AppT ArrowT (VarT a_1627405973))
                                    (ConT GHC.Types.Int)))])
       []
```

If I know the name of `F`, I can look up information about it:

```
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> putStrLn $(stringE . show =<< reify ''F)
FamilyI (FamilyD TypeFam
                 Ghci3.F
                 [PlainTV a_1627405973]
                 (Just StarT))
        []
```

But I can't find the name of `F` in the first place.  Even if I add an instance of the type class, the `InstanceD` has none of the information about the definition:

```
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> instance C' [a] where type F [a] = a ; f' = length
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> f' "Haskell"
7
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> 42 :: F [Integer]
42
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> putStrLn $(stringE . show =<< reify ''C')
ClassI (ClassD [] Ghci3.C' [PlainTV a_1627405973] []
               [SigD Ghci3.f'
                     (ForallT [PlainTV a_1627405973]
                              [ClassP Ghci3.C' [VarT a_1627405973]]
                              (AppT (AppT ArrowT (VarT a_1627405973))
                                    (ConT GHC.Types.Int)))])
       [InstanceD []
                  (AppT (ConT Ghci3.C')
                        (AppT ListT (VarT a_1627406161)))
                  []]
```

If `reify` won't work, is there a workaround, other than listing the associate type synonyms manually?

This problem is present in GHC 7.8.3 with version 2.9.0.0 of the template-haskell package; it was also present in GHC 7.4.2 with version 2.7.0.0 of the template-haskell package.  (I didn't check on GHC 7.6.*, but I imagine it was present there too.)  I'm interested in solutions for any version of GHC (including "this was only fixed in GHC version *V*").

Comment: Have you looked at `reifyInstances`?

Comment: @Kwarrtz: I just tried it now.  It doesn't work, though; it just gives rise to the same `InstanceD`s as I saw with `reify`: `putStrLn $(stringE . show =<< reifyInstances ''C' =<< sequence [[t|[Int]|]])` evaluates to `[InstanceD [] (AppT (ConT Ghci1.C') (AppT ListT (VarT a_1627405978))) []]`, which lacks the type family instances.

Comment: I find it odd that `reify` doesn't return the necessary information. Perhaps `show` is hiding some of the information? Have you tried examining the `Info` object directly?

Comment: @Kwarrtz: I'm afraid `Info`'s `Show` instance is just the derived one, and same for the `Show` instance for `Dec`.  However, I can also check directly, as you asked, and no: `putStrLn $(reify ''C' >>= \i -> case i of ClassI (ClassD _ _ _ _ [SigD _ _]) _ -> stringE "just a SigD" ; _ -> stringE "something else")` produces `just a SigD` – that's really the only thing in the `[Dec]` in the `ClassD`!  (requires `LambdaCase`).  I agree it's odd; that's why I asked this question :-)

Comment: @Abel: [You spoke too soon :-)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32628240/237428)  I mean, it's not *solved*, but now we know that it's impossible!  Your bounty also got me to [file a bug report, #10891](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10891).

Comment: @AntalS-Z, perhaps, or it triggered Yuras to do some research and write his reply. To me, from a Q&A standpoint, a _good answer_ can also be _it is not possible because..._. I'm fine with that. Once (if?) that bug report gets resolved, add a new answer and I'll be happy to award that new answer some bounty again :p

Comment: @Abel: I think we're in violent agreement – your original comment said it wasn't enough to attract a brilliant idea, but it *did* attract Yuras's answer!  I absolutely agree about what a good answer is :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not implemented because nobody requested it.

The odd thing is that TH uses its own AST, which doesn't follow internal compiler's AST. As a result, any new feature (e.g. associated type families) is not automatically available via TH. Some one have to open a ticket and implement it.

For the reference: internal `reifyClass` function [ignores](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/3ec205aec45ec13fc7274d6b019cd7f7654191f4/compiler/typecheck/TcSplice.hs#L1209) associated type families (it is the 5th element of the tuple returned by [`classExtraBigSig`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/3ec205aec45ec13fc7274d6b019cd7f7654191f4/compiler/types/Class.hs#L246), see also definition of [`ClassATItem`](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/3ec205aec45ec13fc7274d6b019cd7f7654191f4/compiler/types/Class.hs#L101).)

Technically it should be easy to implement associated type family support in `reify`, but most likely it will require backward incompatible changes in TH API, e.g. because its AST doesn't seem to support associated type defaults.

**Added:** It is now [implemented](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10891) (without API change btw) and probably will be available in the next `ghc` release.

Comment: Thank you, Yuras!  I've also filed [bug report #10891](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10891) about this.  Note that I don't think it's backwards-incompatible (but don't quote me on that): `reify` returns a `ClassI` containing a [`ClassD`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:ClassD) which contains a `[Dec]`, and I was expecting one of those `Dec`s to be a [`FamilyD`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:FamilyD), which already exists.

Comment: Just what I needed. But I will leave the bounty open [until the grace period](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/), just to allow others to comment and/or prove you wrong ;)

Comment: @AntalS-Z I mean that `FamilyD` doesn't support [associated type synonym defaults](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html#assoc-decl-defs). You are probably not using them, but full solution may require API change.

Comment: @Abel, leaving the bounty open till the end also tends to help good answers attract votes, so it's a more effective way to reward a good answer than awarding it quickly.

Comment: Bounty period expired. This is the best (and only) answer, until or unless [the bug report #10891 is resolved](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10891). Perhaps a good idea to include a link to the bug report in your answer.

Comment: FYI, #10891 is fixed and it's waiting to be merged.

Comment: Any idea why the TH AST differs from the internal one?

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake AFAIK ghc devs want to change internal AST freely without breaking TH API. Probably there are other reasons too.

Comment: I think this (referring to the split between AST implementations) will be rectified as part of [Trees that Grow](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ImplementingTreesThatGrow)